# android : How to change color of selected Item in spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I have made a spinner. The items in the spinner are perfect but when I select an item it is getting displayed in gray color. How to change this color ??
(Color of the selected value not of the items in dropdown list).
As shown in the image below -:

[image]

Comment: public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    Color myColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
   ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(myColor);
    }

Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379851/change-text-color-of-selected-item-in-spinner
It worked for me