# Setting spinner text color programmatically lags, is slow, is wrong color for split second

Tags: android, spinner

**TLDR:** My spinner displays the wrong color for a split second.

I have a problem with my spinner. Whenever I run the app, if the activity is not cached in memory, it sometimes lags. The text is a default color (like black) before I can set it to the right color. It looks really unprofessional.

**Video:**
Please watch this screen recording to see this in action:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By2AG5yaBEhMRnRsbVBDU251STQ/view

How it looks for one split-second while loading the page:
[image]

How it looks after the lag time (and how it is supposed to look from the start):
[image]

**Code:**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        //Get rid of the normal toolbar's title, because the spinner is replacing the title.
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        //Set the choices on the spinner by setting the adapter.
        spinner.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(toolbar.getContext(), new String[]{"Overview", "Story", "Specifications", "Poll", "Video"}, accentColor, backgroundColor));

        //Set the listener for when each option is clicked.
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                //Change the selected item's text color
                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(backgroundColor);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
                                   android:elevation="4dp">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What I was doing wrong:**

Before, I was following the advice of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15380215/2423194), and setting the text color in the `onItemSelected` method, but that method is only called automatically after the UI is done, and you cannot call `onItemSelected` directly from your code. That was causing a lag. (But it is still needed for when you choose an item from the drop down list - see my solution to this question.)

**Solution:**

The strategy is to obtain the "Selected" view and set its text color before onCreate finishes.  When I tested it in the debugger, no UI is shown during the `onCreate` method, so this is guaranteed to work.

I just had to add this code after the call to `setAdapter(...)`:

```
//Set the text color of the Spinner's selected view (not a drop down list view)
spinner.setSelection(0, true);
View v = spinner.getSelectedView();
((TextView)v).setTextColor(backgroundColor);
```

The key point is to call `spinner.setSelection(0, true)` *with the `true` parameter.* Otherwise, if you just call `spinner.setSelection(0)`, the View `v` would be null. I found out about this thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6800839/2423194).

**Complete method:**

Here is the complete method. **NOTE:** The code in `onItemSelected` still needs to be there! Because otherwise, every time you select an item from the drop down list, it will have the wrong color.

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    //Get rid of the normal toolbar's title, because the spinner is replacing the title. 
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); 

    //Set the choices on the spinner by setting the adapter. 
    spinner.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(toolbar.getContext(), new String[]{"Overview", "Story", "Specifications", "Poll", "Video"}, accentColor, backgroundColor));

    //Set the text color of the Spinner's selected view (not a drop down list view)
    spinner.setSelection(0, true);
    View v = spinner.getSelectedView();
    ((TextView)v).setTextColor(backgroundColor);

    //Set the listener for when each option is clicked. 
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    { 

        @Override 
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        { 
           //Change the selected item's text color 
           ((TextView) view).setTextColor(backgroundColor);
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        { 
        } 
    }); 

}
```

For more info on the source code of the setSelection methods, see the AbsSpinner.java code here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-release/core/java/android/widget/AbsSpinner.java

And here is Spinner.java in case it helps: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-release/core/java/android/widget/Spinner.java

Answer (score 0):

If somebody else needs to get separate text color, design, etc. for spinner's selected item and drop-down items you can accomplish it with next code

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
        context,
        R.layout.custom_spinner_title_item,
        tabsArray.map { it.name }.toTypedArray(),
    )
    spinner.adapter = adapter

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)
```

where

`R.layout.custom_spinner_title_item` - design file of your selected item

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` - design file of drop down items

As a result, there is no more need in `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` hack