# In Spinner, Background get not changed when select on perticular item

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

I want to change my spinner item background (not the spinner background) when the item is selected.

**I want it like this:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: this should solve the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379851/change-text-color-of-selected-item-in-spinner

Comment: I don't want to change whole `popupBackground` but I want to change only selected Item popup background

Comment: @ChintakPatel define android:background="@drawable/mybg" and  <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/red"/>. Just go through the answer of the link, that I attached

Comment: @ChintakPatel . .i have added the code for changing text color too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `drawable` under `drawable folder` named

> `my_click_changer`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/your_new_Color" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/your_default_Color" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

**EDIT** this is for changing the `text color`

create another `drawable`

> `text_color_changer`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_checked="true" />
   <item android:color="@android:color/white" />
 </selector>
```

then create a individual layout for each `Spinner` item,

> your_xml_name.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/text1"
   style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:background="@drawable/my_click_changer"
   android:ellipsize="marquee"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:textAlignment="inherit"
   android:textSize="15sp"
   android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_changer"
   android:textStyle="bold" />
```

> And in the code create `Adapter` by

```
    final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.your_xml_name, yourList);
```

Comment: Thank you, I added one more thing,
`<item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_activated="true" />`
and this worked perfectly.

but now as my font is white too, I want when state is activated, my text should be black colored.. so what should I do ?

Comment: @ChintakPatel i have taken this into account.. And please view the **Edit** portion of my answer.. I have already answered to it.. And use you appropirate `colors` too